# Set Windows Update to include Visual Studio

Tags: windows, windows-update, visual-studio

Can I set Windows Update to include also updates to Visual Studio Beta?

For example, Microsoft just announced April update for Visual Studio 11 Beta. It would be great, if I was able to install them the same way I install updates for Windows, Office, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To setup Windows update to scan for Microsoft or other products it can update you will need to do the following:

1. Start menu -> Windows update
2. near the middle/bottom you will see text talking about updating other products on your system, click on the blue text and it should either pop up a website in Internet explorer, or ask if you want to allow it.
3. If it asks you to allow/deny, clicking allow, and then checking for updates should now give you additional updates that you seek

   If it pops up a website, you'll need to follow the guide on it, then check "i accept" and hit the apply equivalent button with the shield on it
4. It should now take you back to your Windows update, and the text will still be there, you need to click on the blue link again, and go back to 3a.

Comment: +1 for extending Windows Update to other MS products.  However, do you know for certain that this will include a beta product as the original question stated?

Comment: Specifically Beta, I'm not sure. I don't know if Microsoft includes Beta update channels in Windows Update. However, it seems to me that the Beta distinction would be declared to Windows Update if it can receive updates through that channel.

Comment: i think the goal post moved. Anyone know how to do this in 2017? Windows 7, I have.